# How can call artisan commands before Test:suite

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Is there a way to call artisan commands before my entire test suite? Installing Cartalyst extensions takes time so I do not want to do it before every test but I am presuming i cannot call facades from a static method like setUpBeforeClass, I receive this error

> RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/lance/Desktop/FastLMS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:218

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();

        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('extension:install');
        Artisan::call('extension:enable');
    }

    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        Hash::setRounds(4);

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']->disableMiddleware();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should run createApplication before Artisan comands

Comment: If i do that then my factories fail with Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function define() on null

Comment: try to run parent::setUpBeforeClass() before commands. If it will not help rename function to setUp() and don't forget run parent::setUp() before Artisan commands

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: Would you please send the full class example

Comment: updated question

Comment: You forget parent::setUpBeforeClass();

Comment: oh yes sorry i had it there before but I still get the same error anyway.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?